# Google Short Url 403 Error

Tags: http-status-code-403, quota, short-url

Currently I have a aws lambda that is scheduled to execute on a specific time every 2 mins for 3 hours. Each execution results to around 60 requests to google short url every 2 mins which is well below the 100 queries per 100 seconds.

The problem is it keeps getting 403 error after around an hour of execution and I am not sure why cause even in the dashboard I am sure we are not hitting the quota.

See image here for Graph

[image]

Any of you guys have any idea why I am still prompted with a 403 error even if I am not hitting quota?

Or do am I not understanding how the quota works?

Comment: Any more info on the response than just the status code?

Comment: Isn't it possible that you're just getting blocked by Google and AWS quota has nothing to do with this?

Comment: Its running for 3 hours and after 1st hour it runs to  this  403 error. I needbto stop cron for 5 minsbthen run it again  and its already ok again and finishes every queue after 30 mins